# Xpath + Selenium/Python div ng-if=

Tags: python, xpath

I have a div which the parts only difference one another between  by the ng-if. I'm trying to find a way to xpath the span[2] inside the div. I'll appreciate any help.

Important observation, the <"----> means that the camp was not register, but it can in the future so div[n] do not will work properly.

below html code:

```
<md-card-content class="md-body-1 layout-sm-column" layout-sm="column" xpath="1">
                <!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.celular" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Celular</span>
                    <span>(21) 99998-4816</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.numeroPaciente" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Número paciente</span>
                    <span>1891</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.cpf" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">CPF do paciente</span>
                    <span>274.228.527-04</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.rg" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">RG</span>
                    <span>61030</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.dtNascimento" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Idade do paciente</span>
                    <span>67 anos
                    </span>
                </div><!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.dtNascimento" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Data de nascimento</span>
                    <span>13 de set de 1952</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.sexo" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Sexo</span>
                    <span>Masculino</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.plano" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Plano</span>
                    <span>Particular</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.titularPlano" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Titular do plano</span>
                    <span>Geap</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!----><div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.numeroCarteirinha" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Número carteirinha</span>
                    <span>0901000276140409</span>
                </div><!---->
                <!---->

                <!---->
                <!---->

                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
                <!---->
            </md-card-content>
```

my code stoped as shown below:

```
 try:
     ngstring = '''"sobreCtrl.paciente.dtNascimento"'''
     Idade_Paciente = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//div[@ng-if="+ngstring+"]//span[2]").text except 
 TimeoutException:
```

any help?

Comment: What's your expected ouput?

Comment: @JackFleeting
the second span value.

<div ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.sexo" layout="" class="layout-row">
                    <span class="grey flex-35" flex="35">Sexo</span>
                    <span>Masculino</span>

eg.: Masculino

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing `ngstring` to

```
sobreCtrl.paciente.sexo
```

and see if it works.

Comment: i got this as error: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div[@ng-if='sobreCtrl.paciente.dtNascimento']//span[2]"}
  (Session info: chrome=81.0.4044.138)

Comment: is it possible to xpath using ng-if ?

Comment: @MarquesDev The full xpath expression for the html in your question is `//div[@ng-if="sobreCtrl.paciente.sexo"]/span[2]`. [You can test it here](http://xpather.com/hGG13rQs). Your actual html may be different from the one in your code.

Comment: I think the problem was the "//" in yours it is using just "/". I alredy knew the Xpath tester but i didn't know how to use. Thanks for helping!